# Tailwind CSS not working with React Native

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

I am using the below code but there's no effect of tailwind classes in the app. Any help will be appreaciable.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {useTailwind} from 'tailwind-rn';

export default function App() {
  const tailwind = useTailwind();
  return (
    <View style={tailwind("flex-1 justify-center items-center")}>
      <Text>Welcome to React-Native!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: first install npm i tailwind-rn
second for automatic setup   npx setup-tailwind-rn
Then wrap the root component with tailwind like below

Comment: Refer this link
https://github.com/vadimdemedes/tailwind-rn

Answer (score 2):

first install npm i tailwind-rn
second for automatic setup   npx setup-tailwind-rn
Then wrap the root component with tailwind like below

[image]

now you can use tailwind

Comment: Okay Aniket. Will give it a try.

Comment: where is the utilities coming from ?

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya import utilities from './tailwind.json';
Follow the instructions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-rn