# Why is my Tailwind CSS not doing anything?

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

For some reason, I cannot get tailwind rn to actually style my program. When I run expo start, the items are not aligned to the center, even though I put that in my code.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import {TailwindProvider} from 'tailwind-rn';
import utilities from './tailwind.json';
import {useTailwind} from 'tailwind-rn';

export default function App() {

  const tailwind = useTailwind();
  return (
    <TailwindProvider utilities={utilities}>
      <View style={tailwind('flex-1 items-center justify-center')}>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
   </TailwindProvider>
    
  );
}
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mari-application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "build:tailwind": "tailwindcss --input input.css --output tailwind.css --no-autoprefixer && tailwind-rn",
    "dev:tailwind": "concurrently \"tailwindcss --input input.css --output tailwind.css --no-autoprefixer --watch\" \"tailwind-rn --watch\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "tailwind-rn": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "concurrently": "^7.2.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Did you follow this step:  `npm install tailwind-rn` and then `npx setup-tailwind-rn`

Comment: Try to use any other class in `<Text>` like `text-red-500` and see whether it works or not.

Comment: @RahmanHaroon yes i have

Comment: @RosePark still does not work

Comment: Have you imported/installed it correctly from https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-rn . Show your package.json file?

Comment: @RosePark I provided my package.json, I followed those directions exactly

Answer (score 1):

For anyone viewing this and not wanting to download an old version, a lot has changed in the past few months - Tailwind is now "NativeWind"

```
yarn add nativewind
yarn add --dev tailwindcss
```

the setup is very similar to regular TailWindCSS, you just need to add your file classes to the tailwind config:

```
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./<custom directory>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

then add the plugin to your babel config:

```
// babel.config.js

module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: ["nativewind/babel"],
  };
};
```

Then you style as normal Tailwind, you can remove the StyleSheet import and provider code as well:

```
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  return (
      <View className='flex-1 items-center justify-center'>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. `install npm i tailwind-rn`
2. `npx setup-tailwind-rn`

Then wrap the root component with the `TailwindProvider` like:

```
import {TailwindProvider} from 'tailwind-rn';
import utilities from './tailwind.json';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import {useTailwind} from 'tailwind-rn';

const App = () => (
const tailwind = useTailwind();
return(
    <TailwindProvider utilities={utilities}>
      <View style={tailwind("flex-1 justify-center items-center")}>
         <Text>wwww</Text>
         <Button title='click me'  /> 
      </View>   
    </TailwindProvider>
 );
)
```

Credits: @Aniket:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71122844/13431819

Or

Downgrade the `tailwind` version to `version-2`

Comment: I have done that, but it is still not adjusting to the center.

Comment: Try to do the following steps in a new project. May be some package got wrongly installed

Comment: still has no effect, no errors; my text is just stuck in the top left instead of the center.

Comment: Try to downgrade to 2nd version of `tailwind-css`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just downloading an older version of tailwind and it worked fine.

Comment: Can you provide the version you downgraded?